# specific argument in an output in AWS S3 CLI commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, aws-s3-client

Do you know how can I see a specific argument in the output using AWS S3 CLI?
For example, I want to see the output

> KeyCount

after using the command [list-objects-v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html).

Comment: Strangely, I am unable to see `KeyCount` in the output of the `list-objects-v2` command. Have you been able to see it in the returned output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the global option `--debug`
it will make your request and reply verbose.